# Laravel Json column & value is interger with where?

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

subcategory_id column data are in JSON format
like :

```
["3","4","5"]
```

Now I want to select all data from the table where subcategory_id = 3. How can I do this with Laravel query builder?

Comment: use JSON where condititons https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#json-where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this.

```
DB::table('table_name')->whereJsonContains('subcategory_id ','3')->get();
```

Comment: Yeap, Thanks for answering. I already did it but it didn't work cause of joining with the JSON column.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `whereJsonContains`. Make sure you are inserting the data in a proper format, because you wouldn't get an error if you try to insert to JSON column like this:

```
YourTable::factory()->create([
   'subcategory_id' => '3' // this should be like ['3']
]);
```

If the data is inserted properly, you can use `whereJsonContains`,

```
YourTable::whereJsonContains('subcategory_id', "3")->get();
```

Which returns all rows having "3" in `subcategory_id` array column.

> This feature is not supported by the SQLite database